How to make tree.exe command available in powershell?
I'm using tree.exe from Cygwin, as the preferred version over the severely outdated and usless windows tree.com version found in C:\Windows\System32.
Since it runs fine in powershell when dot-sourcing it using:
. 'C:\cygwin64\bin\tree.exe', I hoped I could just replace the Windows one, by moving it there and renaming tree.com to tree_disabled.com. However, this doesn't work. The command gives no error and nothing at all happens. So I have no idea what's going on, as I already tried copying the ACL from tree.com to tree.exe, and checking the PATH.
How can I make my tree.exe run as a normal command from powershell?

Set-Alias tree C:\cygwin64\bin\tree.exe in your profile should do the trick

you can't overwrite system files, they're protected so any changes will be detected and reverted by dism or sfc /scannow

Or put c:\cygwin64\bin first in the path.  I don't see why you can't run tree.exe.

I seem to have forgotten that most Cygwin binaries are not statically compiled, so they all depend on having the Cygwin1.dll in the same directory. However, for some unknown reason, the DLL popup warning never showed up for me, until after having restarted my machine.



So there are (at least) 3 solutions here:

Copy both your Cygwin binary (here tree.exe) and cygwin1.dll to a separate directory in you PATH.

Create a symbolic link to the already existing binary in C:\Cygwin64\bin\tree.exe.

Create an alias in your Powershell $PROFILE, pointing to the original binary.
Set-Alias tree 'C:\cygwin64\bin\tree.exe'




IMPORTANT

Do not place the copied binaries into the C:\\Windows\System32 directory. And as mentioned in comments, do not rename or change anything here, as it will be overwritten on your next windows update. Instead, place them in a separate directory in you path.

This is probably a bad idea, if you're also using git-bash or MinGW64/MSYS shells as they have their own Cygwin commands for the same. So there is  no telling which version will take precedence in those shells. (And it's easy to forget what you did.)




